# Elasticsearch 8 Java Client ResponseException status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found] {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

Tags: java, elasticsearch, client, http-status-code-404

this is Michael from germany and i am reaching out to you because i have to finish my master thesis before 31.10.2022.

I had working code in july 2022 which i didn't touch since then. I used the online 2 weeks trial vom elastic.co to connect and do my stuff. Now i want to execute the code again on a new 2 weeks trial but i am facing an error, which i can't solve.
What happened in the meanwhile:
a) in july i used version 8.2.0 of the software while meanwhile Elasticsearch company released
version 8.4.0 of their software.
b) i changed password in the code, because i have a new 2 weeks trial now.

Here are some short example codes which all fail (actually my real code is bigger but these are small examples). Only the code after the line `// "productive code"` changes

Creating an index:

```
package Kapselung;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;

public class create_index {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String host = "";
        int port =;
        RestClient restClient;
        ElasticsearchClient ESClient;

        // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html
        // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/_basic_authentication.html
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching();
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        };

        // Create the low-level client
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, "https"));
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback);
        restClient = restClientBuilder.build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        ESClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        // "productive code"
        try {
            ESClient.indices().create(c -> c.index("products100"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Failure is:

```
co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/indices.create] Failed to decode error response
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:290)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.create(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:266)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.create(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:282)
    at Kapselung.create_index.main(create_index.java:51)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [https://gattinger-fourth.kb.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243], URI [/products100], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]

    ... 5 more
```

Or posting a document:

```
package Kapselung;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Request;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Response;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;

public class post_document {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "elastic";
        String password = "JotkB5QY5v9IN0qRtvf6d5dL";
        String host = "gattinger-fourth.kb.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io";
        int port = 9243;
        RestClient restClient;
        ElasticsearchClient ESClient;

        // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html
        // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/_basic_authentication.html
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching();
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        };

        // Create the low-level client
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, "https"));
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback);
        restClient = restClientBuilder.build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        ESClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        // "productive code"
        try {
            Request request = new Request("POST", "/products100/_doc");
            String document = "{\"sku\": \"21847816\",\"name\": \"Rasierapparat\",\"price\": 23.99}";
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // Jackson Json
            request.setJsonEntity(mapper.writeValueAsString(document));
            Response response = restClient.performRequest(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

failure:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [https://gattinger-fourth.kb.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243], URI [/products100/_doc], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:346)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:287)
    at Kapselung.post_document.main(post_document.java:59)
```

Or just checking the Elasticsearch version:

```
package Kapselung;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;

public class getESClient_info_version_number {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "elastic";
        String password = "JotkB5QY5v9IN0qRtvf6d5dL";
        String host = "gattinger-fourth.kb.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io";
        int port = 9243;
        RestClient restClient;
        ElasticsearchClient ESClient;

        // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html
        // https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/_basic_authentication.html
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
            @Override
            public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching();
                return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            }
        };

        // Create the low-level client
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, "https"));
        restClientBuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback);
        restClient = restClientBuilder.build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
        ESClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        // "productive code"
        try {
            System.out.println(ESClient.info().version().number());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Failure:

```
co.elastic.clients.transport.TransportException: [es/info] Missing [X-Elastic-Product] header. Please check that you are connecting to an Elasticsearch instance, and that any networking filters are preserving that header.
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.checkProductHeader(RestClientTransport.java:351)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:253)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.info(ElasticsearchClient.java:976)
    at Kapselung.getESClient_info_version_number.main(getESClient_info_version_number.java:51)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [https://gattinger-fourth.kb.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243], URI [/], status line [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>00003</groupId>
  <artifactId>00004</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.2.0</version>
    </dependency>




<!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
-->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- benötigt falls ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider
    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/installation.html -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Changing dependency from 8.2.0 to 8.4.0 didn't help.

So i don't know what actually to do. Do you?

Yes i know that i spread the password, it is intentional so somebody could help me by actually executing it. It is only a 2 weeks trial so i don't care about the logindata.

Thanks - Enomine

Comment: Read this [post](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/74). What is version Elasticsearch?